# How to write two expressions as just one?

Tags: perl

Can I write these two:

```
$var =  tied $$var;  # History=HASH(0x192a540)
$var->{ desc };      # object description info
```

By one expression:

```
${tied $$var}->{ desc };
```

I get the error:

```
Not a SCALAR reference at ...
```

Comment: Regarding your `ref_name` example: then what is the `$z` or `$var`? At least print out `$var` or `ref $var` to debug that error message. And get rid of the `tied`, this seems to be a red herring for the purpose of debugging this problem.

Comment: @amon: I delete my **UPD**s because I try dereference after reassign `$var =  tied $$var`. New variable name helps too.

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=references+quick+reference : from #1 this is `${tied($$var)}{desc}` and from #3 can be `tied($$var)->{desc}` (parentheses are necessary for precedence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `SOMETHING->{key}` tries to perform hash lookup in a reference `SOMETHING`. Here, your `SOMETHING` is `${...}`, i.e. a *scalar dereference*.

Instead, you want

- normal parentheses: `(...)->{key}`
- hash access without an extra level of dereferencing: `${...}{key}`.

The `->` dereference operator is only optional *between* two subscripts. I.e. `$foo{bar}[42]` and `$foo{bar}->[42]` are equivalent and access a value from the `%foo` hash. But `$foo->{bar}[42]` is completely different: This accesses a value in the `$foo` hash reference.

The syntax `%{SOMETHING}{key}` is not correct because that dereferences `SOMETHING` as a hash, then access an entry. But the syntax for accessing an entry in a hash `%SOMETHING` is `$SOMETHING{key}`, not `%SOMETHING{key}`. The sigil `%` of a hash turns into a scalar sigil `$` because you get a scalar entry out of the hash. This is known to be confusing, and has been fixed in Perl 6.

Comment: @EugenKonkov In your question, you first reassign the `$var = tied $$var`. Are you trying my suggestions after that code (where `$var` was reassigned), or *instead* of that code? You may want to use a different variable name, instead of reassigning.

Comment: heh... yes. I forget to delete reassigning (